# Why does deleting directories generate error messages with find -exec?

Tags: bash, find, osx, rm, bsd

Why is it that:

```
find . -type d -name test -exec rm -r {} \;
```

generates error messages:

```
find: ./foo/test: No such file or directory
find: ./bar/test: No such file or directory
find: ./blech/test: No such file or directory
```

even though it actually deletes the relevant directories ?

This is with OS X (10.10).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find uses `readdir()` to get the content from directories.

As readdir() is a library function that implements caching and as `find` even without caching cannot know that the called program removes a just discovered directory, a standard find call will always cause such errors.

There is a clean solution for your problem:

`find . -depth ...`

(replace ... by the rest of the find command line)

will tell `find` to process all directory content before the directory itself.

BTW: I recommend you to read the `find` man page. Since 26 years, there is a better solution than `-exec ... {} \;` as this is slow and creates a sub-process for every hit. Look for `-exec ... {} +`, as this collects path names until the max size of arguments is reached.

Answer (score 1):

### Original question

All words after `-exec` up to `\;` are interpreted as parameters, i.e. they are expanded by the shell from where you run the command (you can try what happens if a directory named `{}` exists), but then they are interpreted as if quoted. You need a shell to expand globs:

```
find . -type d -exec bash -c 'echo {}/*' \;
```

### Update

When deleting directories, after you delete a parent directory, you can no longer delete its children - they're gone.

Comment: Sorry - I just simplified the question while you were posting your answer - it seems I was wrong and that even the first example (`find . -type d -name test -exec rm -r {} \;`) fails - does your answer still apply?

Comment: @PaulR: Check the update.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I get `find: illegal option -- t`.

Comment: @PaulR: Maybe add a dot before?